# GPL-compatible database of country & region names

Tags: database, location, gis

For WordPress's sister project BuddyPress, we are looking for relatively-reputable resources that manage a list of countries and regions. Due to the WordPress OpenSource philosophy, we are only seeking GPL-compatible resources.

If no such resources exist, we could possibly consider GPL-compatible services as well.

Or there could possibly be a GlotPress-like service (see http://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp/dev) wherein the community contributes and maintains the database which can be downloaded via a link or API.

So far all the databases/services I have found have either been commercial or otherwise incompatible with GPL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems unfortunate to set off on another data collection effort when there are already volunteers world-wide contributing to the [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) collection that is available under a [Creative Commons license](http://www.geonames.org/export/#terms). Does BuddyPress really want to get into the business of maintaining administrative area data that are always changing?

Comment: What gives you the impression that "BuddyPress wants to get into the business of...another data collection effort"? I asked about GPL-compatible services that are doing this so that we can leverage their work.

Comment: "we are looking for relatively-reputable resources that manage a list of countries and regions", "wherein the community contributes and maintains the database" gave me the impression you want some GPL-ed service to provide the data+software. I was pointing out that community maintained data exists that is Creative Commons licensed. A "GPL-compatible database of names" seems like a duplication of effort. There are questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243196/what-is-the-difference-between-creative-commons-and-gpl-licensing to suggest not GPL-ing data. Perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks! That link is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I agree GeoNames is a good resource.  I would also bring up OpenStreetMap, which is under an Open Data Commons Open Database License (see http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/).